# Is there a sample for using the REST IoT Foundation API?

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, iot

The IBM IoT Foundation technology has an API that is REST based.  The low level docs for the API can be found here:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#/

with a higher level article here:

https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/devices/api.html

Unfortunately, despite having tried a number of experiments, I am unable to get any REST requests working.  Is there a recipe, tutorial or sample available that illustrates the use of the IoT Foundation APIs using REST requests?

Comment: @BenRondeau ... thanks Ben, the screen shot provided by mdickens gave me all the info I needed.  It showed where I had entered bad information.  Y'all might want to review the docs supplied to make sure that there is enough information available for a future reader to put all the pieces together.

Comment: Awesome. Happy hacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a screenshot with steps for how to get started using the IBM IoT Foundation REST Api to perform [GET organization details](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Organization_Configuration/get) using the Firefox RESTClient. Does this help to get you started?

[image: Screenshot of how to get started using the IBM IoT Foundation REST Api to GET organzation information]

Comment: Details about how to get an api key are here [register](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/getting_started/register/index.html)

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  That was EXACTLY the information I needed to use.  After seeing your recipe, I realized that I was supplying "use-auth-token" as my userid in the Basic Authentication which is, of course, very wrong.  I'd like to suggest that the pages found as reference in my original post be updated with the instructions you supplied in your screen shot.  Again, MANY thanks.